# What is the lightest weight solution for controlling 2 machines from the same monitor(s)

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, vnc

I have 2 desktops at the office. I use the main one in dual monitor mode and I tend to max out its meager reasources between web browsers (for code testing) a music or other media player and all of my developer tools. I want to be able to use the second machine for non-developement tasks but I do not want to have to toggle my monitor back and forth and/or switch keyboards and mice to do that.

What is the lightest weight (on the main machine) solution for controlling 2 machines from the same monitor(s)?

Both machines are WinXP sp3.

**Edit**

I'd like to go with a software solution that allows me to manipulate both machines more or less simultaneously. Changing my focus from the screen to a KVM to switch back and forth just to change music tracks might be more hassle than it saves in resources.

Of the various VNS client/servers and Windows's own Remote Desktop, which uses the least overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but if you had an additional monitor for your other computer, you could use [Synergy-plus](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) to control both systems with a single keyboard and mouse.  It will also synchronize the clipboards between systems.

It is a lot more usable than keeping a remote desktop session open, but of course, it does require an additional monitor.

Comment: +1 I have been using Synergy forever, didn't know about "plus", but it easily the best soultion, I used KVM and if you check out the screen shot on the link, that is exactly how my setup looks. I use dual monitors for one computer and a single monitor for the second computer. You can't beat the clipboard functionality either. You can't go wrong with this solution, fork out $100 bucks for the additional monitor

Comment: Wow, this looks great. I remember looking into synergy a few years ago, and it seemed too young and hard to configure at the time, but this looks much more mature. I will definitely check this out!

Comment: I didn't mention it because of the single monitor requirement, but I use it myself at work and it is brilliant. 4 Desktops, 2 Machines. One running Vista and another running 7.

Answer (score 6):

[VNC](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.realvnc.com%2F&ei=sDmVSqO_FI6uMLKl5PkH&usg=AFQjCNEK5ZK_yglptI3-ZNVrtJFomb20ZA&sig2=YnZQffgj3EHY5XGd58xmJg) or [Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/getstarted/remoteintro.mspx). Minimize/close it when you don't need the second PC.

Comment: as they are both windows, remote desktop would be the easiest/fastest/best solution imo

Answer (score 5):

When you mean 'toggle' your monitor - your not excluding a [**KVM Switch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) are you?

A **KVM Switch** is the lightest weight solution as it is a hardware only soltuion. Note that a KVM is only going to be practical if the secondary machine is physically close to your primary machine as cables from the switch need to be run.

A **Remote Desktop** solution, as mentioned in other answers has no limitations on physical machine location, although being on the LAN would be preferred for performance reasons. For this case, I would go with **Windows Remote Desktop**. It's free, built into Windows, and I've never ever had an issue with it. I use it for all of my remote system administration within my office and at home.

Comment: Remote Desktop is much easier and more convenient than a KVM switch.  At least it is in my experience.

Comment: My experience is the exact opposite. KVM switches are much easier and more convenient than Remote Desktop. To each his own...

Comment: If he is maxing out "meager" resources on his primary machine, he will be using up even more on that machine by running remote desktop. A KVM would have zero bearing on performance.

Comment: I've done both, KVM and Remote Desktop and I tend to prefer the KVM if possible, but Remote Desktop if I don't have a KVM.

Comment: If Remote Desktop craps out, you can't see what's going on. It's either switch the screen or reset the machine. On the other hand of course some KVMs don't play well with mice and you can end up with a non functioning mouse on one machine until you reboot.

Comment: True, a KVM would be the lightest weight, but its more involved than simply moving the mouse and may distract me from the task at hand... something to consider as they are much cheaper now than when I last purchased one (hint it had PS/2 support)

Comment: KVM requires physical proximity of machine. Remote Desktop requires network connectivity.

Comment: On the other hand Remote Desktop is sllooooowww in comparison to KVM, even on our local 100 MBit network.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a cheap [DVI switch](http://www.amazon.de/HQ-DVI-HDMI-UMSCHALTER-AUDIO/dp/B000J103IO/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=ce-de&qid=1251295289&sr=8-4) from Amazon for about 11 EUR. It's not a full-blown KVM, but if you are only looking for a way to switch monitor signals that's probably the cheapest solution. Despite some negative reviews at amazon, it does work well on my system. No problems with playback of Blu-Ray DVDs either. And it's not as slow and sluggish as RemoteDesktop.

**Edit:** Combine this with [Synergy-plus](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) as Dlux suggested and you should be done.